# How to convert string to "iso-8859-1"?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i convert an UTF-8 string into an ISO-8859-1 string?

Comment: There are only UTF-16 strings in .NET. *Anything* else is an array of bytes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
        System.Text.Encoding iso_8859_1 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        System.Text.Encoding utf_8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        // Unicode string.
        string s_unicode = "abcéabc";

        // Convert to ISO-8859-1 bytes.
        byte[] isoBytes = iso_8859_1.GetBytes(s_unicode);

        // Convert to UTF-8.
        byte[] utf8Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(iso_8859_1, utf_8, isoBytes);
```

Comment: Ahh, never knew about the Convert method  :)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I output this:
  Response.Write(isoBytes)  does not work?

Comment: byte[] srcBytes = utf_8.GetBytes(srcstr);
            byte[] tgtBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(utf_8, iso_8859_1, srcBytes);


            Response.Write(tgtBytes);

Answer (score 5):

.NET Strings are all UTF-16 internally. There is no UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 encoded `System.String` in .NET. To get the binary representation of the string in a particular encoding use `System.Text.Encoding` class:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes("hello world");
```

Comment: Almost  ;)  UTF8 string -> bytes -> ISO-88590-1 string

Comment: @leppie: What's a UTF8 or ISO-88590-1 string? Are those anything except a sequence of bytes?