# Converting Html utf-8 charset to ISO-8859-1 via C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, encode, iso-8859-1

I've been struggling to convert a html value of an attribute, without any success.

Here is the the HTML i am trying to convert (sure the charset will not be shown here, but, i see it exactly as you see it).

```
<a href="https://sistemas.usp.br/jupiterweb/listarGradeCurricular?codcg=12&amp;codcur=12012&amp;codhab=1&amp;tipo=N" target="_blank">Administração – São Paulo – diurno</a>
```

All right, the VALUE of this htmlnode is "Administração - São Paulo - diurno".

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to parse the HtmlPage for this, and once i reach this node, its innerText value is just like this : `AdministraÃ§Ã£o â SÃ£o Paulo â diurno`

I am assuming the original charset of the page is UTF-8 because thats what the encoding tag on the html says to me.

How can i convert this weird string to : `Administração - São Paulo - Diurno` ?

I've tried these threads already : [thread one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922199/c-sharp-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-latin1-h) and [thread two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629617/how-to-convert-string-to-iso-8859-1)
and nothing solved my issue

**EDIT: I am getting the page via a C# WebRequest Get.**

**EDIT2 : Added HtmlAgilityPack  tag**

The problem was isolated : WebRequest is messing the Html sometimes.

Is there any other way to set the encoding ? i am trying : _webReq.Encoding = "ISO-8859-1"

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you should tag it with HtmlAgilityPack, looks like that's where the problem is. Are you retrieving this data from a database? If you put a profiler on it, is the data correctly shown?

Comment: I will Edit to make it clearer, and tag it with HtmlAgilityPack.
I am getting the page via webrequest c#

Comment: That's important as well. I believe you can set the encoding when getting it via WebRequest, give me a minute

Comment: Yes you can, i will try it now.

Comment: Set the Encoding to "ISO-8859-1", not worked.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint after getting the response, is the content properly shown? I'm trying to isolate the Request or the HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: No, the html comes "messed" right after the request, so its the WebRequest.
Thanks for that, now we know where to focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a small test, you can see that the string is not properly getting Encoded back to its original form.

Sample test:

```
 var item = "Administração - São Paulo - Diurno";
 Console.WriteLine(item);

 var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item);
 var item2 = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
 Console.WriteLine(item2);
```

This prints:

```
Administraçao - Sao Paulo - Diurno
AdministraA§A£o - SA£o Paulo - Diurno
```

As you can see, the original string is being converted to bytes using [UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx), but then it is being converted back to a string using [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx) encoding.

This is wrong.

If WebRequest.GetResponse() is returning the string as the wrong value, then there is a problem with that method. Try setting the [TransferEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.transferencoding.aspx) property on the HttpWebRequest to UTF8.

> Before you can set the TransferEncoding property, you must first set the SendChunked property to true. Clearing TransferEncoding by setting it to null has no effect on the value of SendChunked. Values assigned to the TransferEncoding property replace any existing contents.

Or you can try to set the Encoding to UTF8 on the StreamReader you open. Can I see your code?

Answer (score 0):

i solved with:

```
    HtmlWeb Webget = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    Webget.AutoDetectEncoding = false;
    Webget.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    doc_tmp.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
    doc_tmp.OptionReadEncoding = true;
    doc_tmp.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
    doc_tmp.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            doc_tmp.LoadHtml(tmp.InnerHtml);
            doc_tmp.Save(Console.Out);
```