# How to set encoding in SLUG Header using WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, http, encoding, webclient

I'm working in a project that needs to upload a file into a web application using WebClient.

I tried with the following code but the server doesn't recognize the special characters defined in the slug header and replaces them with other not printable characters.

```
WebClient.Headers.Clear();
WebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type",GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension("aáñÑ.pdf")));
WebClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
WebClient.Headers.Add("Referer", myRefererURL);
WebClient.Headers.Add("x-csrf-token", "securityTokenFromModel");
WebClient.Headers.Add("slug", "aáñÑ.pdf");
```

Also, after reading rfc2047 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) I replaced the last line with the following code, but server doesn't recognize the request and returns an error.

```
WebClient.Headers.Add("slug", "(=?ISO-8859-1?q?" + "aáñÑ.pdf" + "?=)");
```

Is there another way to set the enconding charset to allow using special characters (accents, spanish characters) in the slug header?

Edit:

After reading @Julian answer, I tried to change the slug header to look like this:

```
WebClient.Headers.Add("slug", "The Beach at S%C3%A8te");
```

But the web application sets the filename exactly: "The Beach at S%C3%A8te".

In another test, this is how Fiddler shows the request using filename "Documentación Ññ.docx":

Request made by Internet Explorer 11: OK

[image: Request made by Internet Explorer 11: OK]

Request made by .NET WebClient and Google Chrome: ERROR

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to escape the slug value by `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`? I mean something like `WebClient.Headers.Add("slug", "(=?ISO-8859-1?q?" + System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("aáñÑ.pdf") + "?=)");` this.

Comment: Thanks @Ali but it didn't work. Using WebClient.Headers.Add("slug", "(=?ISO-8859-1?q?" + System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("aáñÑ.pdf") + "?=)"); returns an error from the server and using WebClient.Headers.Add("slug", "(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("aáñÑ.pdf")); sets the filename with encoded characters.

Comment: I think you need to encode the file name into `ISO-8859-1` before sending.  Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629617/how-to-convert-string-to-iso-8859-1

Comment: encoding the filename returns an array of bytes, do you know if this array can be sent into the header?

Comment: Forget about what I said about encoding the header values. Have you tried to set webClient `Encoding`? Something like `client.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;` And don't forget to remove `(=?ISO-8859-1?q?`.

Comment: @Ali Yes, I also tried setting webclient encoding to UTF8 but without success. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the specification:

"The field value is the percent-encoded value of the UTF-8 encoding of the character sequence to be included (see Section 2.1 of [RFC3986] for the definition of percent encoding, and [RFC3629] for the definition of the UTF-8 encoding).

Implementation note: to produce the field value from a character sequence, first encode it using the UTF-8 encoding, then encode all octets outside the ranges %20-24 and %26-7E using percent encoding (%25 is the ASCII encoding of "%", thus it needs to be escaped). To consume the field value, first reverse the percent encoding, then run the resulting octet sequence through a UTF-8 decoding process."

https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5023.html#rfc.section.9.7.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question to show results of another tests I made.

Comment: When you say "sets the filename", what are you referring to? The URI of the created resource? In which case the server would be working exactly they way it should.

Comment: What I meant is that the uploaded file in the server gets "The Beach at S%C3%A8te" as its filename (with the percent signs and numbers) and I think these should be replaced by their corresponding special characters in latin charset.

Comment: From an HTTP point of view, "filename" is irrelevant. What is the *URI* of the created resource?

Comment: I don't have direct access to the file URI. To download the file I need to make a request to an URL (I'm trying to replicate user interaction with a web app, I don't request a REST service directly). URL of a file uploaded correctly with IE: `http://sd1.sd2.pre.corp:8080/archive?get&docId=A38C3B5801EF8397E1000000B45D&compId=Documentaci%25C3%25B3nde%25C3%2591%25C3%25B1.docx` and the URL of a file uploaded incorrectly with Webclient : `http:/sd1.sd2.pre.corp:8080/archive?get&docId=FF8F3B5801EF8397E1000000B45D&compId=Documentaci%25EF%25BF%25BDnde%25EF%25BF%25BD%25EF%25BF%25BD.docx`

Comment: URI == URL.

So yes, it seems like the header is processing the Slug header field incorrectly.